# Where can I find fully trained deep networks for download?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning

I'm trying to examine a hypothesis about the statistics of trained "deep" networks. There have been quite a few impressive results published in recent years (most recently, state of the art state detection based on multi-layer neural networks). It's proved to be surprisingly difficult to find code that describes the "final" networks used in these articles.

Does anyone know of a decent source for trained networks that achieved very competitive results? I'm interesting specifically in the layout of trained networks right now, not code that re-produces them.

Comment: Many of these networks are protected academic work, and doesn't get published - and they are seldom of a simple network structure. These networks have a specific "hand coded" structure, so they would require a fair bit of coding.

Comment: Thanks for that. I'm aware that the topology of these networks may be quite exquisite and not very regular, but no matter how hand coded a network is, it would ultimately be just a (long) list of weights that connect a list of nodes. 

Re: protected academic work. I'm hoping some of the academics working in the field realize that sharing results is beneficial to our common cause and promotes their self interest as it allows collaborative results. I realize full publication of results is rare, but it's certainly not unheard of.

Comment: You can find the speech recognition network files in android under some weird folder. But you would need to reverse engineer its binary format.

Answer (score 3):

In [caffe's model zoo](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/docs/model_zoo.md) You can find the topology of pre-trained networks as well as the binary weight files, from several different applications and papers.

Comment: Thanks for that Anona. I'll add that I've also found [matconvent](http://www.vlfeat.org/matconvnet/), which contains excellent examples of a few state-of-the-art neural networks implemented in MATLAB, which makes for easy investigation!